# Transitional semantics for a process algebra on LaTeX

Tags: languages, logicproof

As posted in the title, I'm struggling to find out a way to write the following transitional semantics on LaTeX for a master thesis.

[image]

Anyone can help me?

**Edit 1**: As suggested in the comment, I've tried to write the transition rule one by one, with poor result:

```
Tau $\overline{\langle\tau . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow}\langle P, \rho\rangle}$
$O u t_{C} \frac{v=\llbracket e \rrbracket}{\langle c ! e . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{c ! v}{\longrightarrow}\langle P, \rho\rangle}$
Out $_{Q} \overline{\langle c ! q . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\mathrm{c!} q}{\longrightarrow}\langle P, \rho\rangle}$
Meas $\frac{M=\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_{i} E^{i}, p_{i}=\operatorname{tr}\left(E_{\tilde{r}}^{i} \rho\right)>0}{\langle M[\tilde{r} ; x] . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow} \sum_{i \in I} p_{i}\left\langle P\left\{\lambda_{i} / x\right\}, E_{\tilde{r}}^{i} \rho E_{\tilde{r}}^{i} / p_{i}\right\rangle}$
$\operatorname{Com}_{C} \frac{\left\langle P_{1}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{c ? v}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{1}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle,\left\langle P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{c ! v}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{2}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle}{\left\langle P_{1} \| P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{1}^{\prime} \| P_{2}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle}$
```

etc...

The problems are mostly two: I cannot align the name of the transition and the "fract", and I don't know how to "insert" the second column of transitions.

**Edit 2:**

As splendidly suggested by KersouMan (big up to you), his method works here's the complete code:

```
\begin{align*}
    Tau & \quad\frac{}{\langle\tau.P,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{\tau}\langle P,\rho\rangle} 
        & Op & \quad \frac {}{\langle\mathcal{E}[\tilde{r}] . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P, \mathcal{E}_{\tilde{r}}(\rho)\right\rangle}\\ 
    Inp_C & \quad\frac{v\in\mathsf{Real}}{\langle c?x.t,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{c?v}\langle t\{v/x\},\rho\rangle} 
        & Out_{C} & \quad\frac{v = \llbracket e\rrbracket}{\langle c!e.P,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{e!v}\langle P,\rho\rangle} \\
    Inp_{Q} & \quad\frac{r\not\in qv(x?q.P)}{\langle c?q.P,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{c?r}\langle P\{r/q\},\rho\rangle} 
        & Out_{Q} & \quad \frac{}{\langle c ! q . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\mathrm{c!} q}{\longrightarrow}\langle P, \rho\rangle}\\
     Meas & \quad \frac{M=\sum_{i \in I} \lambda_{i} E^{i}, p_{i}=\operatorname{tr}\left(E_{\tilde{r}}^{i} \rho\right)>0}{\langle M[\tilde{r} ; x] . P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow} \sum_{i \in I} p_{i}\left\langle P\left\{\lambda_{i} / x\right\}, E_{\tilde{r}}^{i} \rho E_{\tilde{r}}^{i} / p_{i}\right\rangle}
        & Par & \quad  \frac{\left\langle P_{1}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu, q b v(\alpha) \cap q v\left(P_{2}\right)=\emptyset}{\left\langle P_{1} \| P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu \| P_{2}}\\
    Com_{C} & \quad \frac{\left\langle P_{1}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{c ? v}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{1}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle,\left\langle P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{c ! v}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{2}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle}{\left\langle P_{1} \| P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{1}^{\prime} \| P_{2}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle}
        & Com_{Q} & \quad \frac{\left\langle P_{1}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\mathrm{c} ? r}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{1}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle, \quad\left\langle P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\mathrm{c} ! r}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{2}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle}{\left\langle P_{1} \| P_{2}, \rho\right\rangle \stackrel{\tau}{\longrightarrow}\left\langle P_{1}^{\prime} \| P_{2}^{\prime}, \rho\right\rangle}\\
    Rel & \quad \frac{\langle P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu}{\langle P[f], \rho\rangle \stackrel{f(\alpha)}{\longrightarrow} \mu[f]} 
        & Sum & \quad \frac{\langle P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu}{\langle P+Q, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu}\\
    Res & \quad \frac{\langle P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu, c n(\alpha) \cap L=\emptyset}{\langle P \backslash L, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu \backslash L} 
        & Cho & \quad \frac{\langle P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu, \llbracket b \rrbracket=\mathrm{tt}}{\langle\text { if } b \text { then } P, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu}\\
    Def & \quad \frac{\langle t\{\tilde{v} / \tilde{x}, \tilde{r} / \tilde{q}\}, \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu, A(\tilde{x}, \tilde{q}):=t, \tilde{v}=\llbracket \tilde{e}]]}{\langle A(\tilde{e}, \tilde{r}), \rho\rangle \stackrel{\alpha}{\longrightarrow} \mu}
\end{align*}
```

the last problem is that now i cannot align the full block to the center and it does not fit on the page:

[image]

I've obviously trying to use the classic command: `\begin{align}...\end{align` but it doesn't work, any advice?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! What have you tried so far? Please show us the code you have ...

Comment: you can just use `\frac` semantically it's not a fraction, but latex won't complain

Comment: Added an edit for the code I have written, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the questions presented after the edit, I would suggest using the `align` environment to get the two columns.
The `\quad` command is here only to add spacing between the name of the transition and the "fractions".
The `stmaryrd` package is here for the `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` commands (to have the double square brackets).

In addition, a problem encountered by the OP is that, for some transitions, the fraction line cannot be aligned with the name of the transition.
This is caused by the use of `\overline` for the first transition (for example) but it is perfectly OK to use `\frac` with empty numerator.
This way, the transitions with an empty upper part will be aligned exatcly as the ones having both an upper and a lower part.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    Tau & \quad\frac{}{\langle\tau.P,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{\tau}\langle P,\rho\rangle} & Inp_C & \quad\frac{v\in\mathsf{Real}}{\langle c?x.t,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{c?v}\langle t\{v/x\},\rho\rangle}\\
    Out_{C} & \quad\frac{v = \llbracket e\rrbracket}{\langle c!e.P,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{e!v}\langle P,\rho\rangle} & Inp_{Q} & \quad\frac{r\not\in qv(x?q.P)}{\langle c?q.P,\rho\rangle\xrightarrow{c?r}\langle P\{r/q\},\rho\rangle}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

The proposed code produces the following result:

[image]

**EDIT**

For better letter spacing in the names of the transitions (Tau, Inp, ...), these names could be encapsulated in `\textit` or `\mathit` commands as `\textit{Inp}_{C}` or `\mathit{Inp}_{C}`.

Comment: That's absolutely fantastic, thank you! The only problem is that right-side fraction are out of the document, there is a way to "center" all the 'align' section?

Comment: I've added the complete solution and the last little problem.

Comment: The problem are the margins of your document which are too small for the width of your equations. I guess a solution would be to reorganize your transitions to have all the wide "fractions" in the same column, this way one of your column will be tighter and should not go out of the page width.

Comment: Smart trick, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

To resize equation You can try This as an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{extreport}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{.4\textwidth}{!}{$\dot{\rho}= \dfrac{x^3}{45a^9-23b}$}
\resizebox{.2\textwidth}{!}{$\dot{\rho}= \dfrac{x^3}{45a^9-23b}$}
\resizebox{.1\textwidth}{!}{$\dot{\rho}= \dfrac{x^3}{45a^9-23b}$}
\resizebox{.05\textwidth}{!}{$\dot{\rho}= \dfrac{x^3}{45a^9-23b}$}
\end{document}
```

[image]